# How to solve image upload on Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I'm having problems uploading pictures. Here is a print sreen of the problem, I didn't work on this site until now. I can't upload image and when I select the file shows the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` and `v.event.remove`. I have no idea what is the problem, I disabled all the plugins but the problem remains. Please help and Thank you!

[image: wordpress image upload]

**Edit**
I discovered that the problem is the theme I'm using, but still haven't found what is exactly!

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your plugins?

Comment: Yes I did but the problem remains

Comment: That is a recursion error. You'll need to locate it, and resolve it.

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running?

Comment: in your shoes I would `grep` the theme for any line containing `v.event.remove`. Check your theme's functions.php for anything suspicious, you can disable functions one at a time by commenting them out.

Comment: @thgaskell version is 3.5.2

Comment: @JPLew  I checked functions.php everthing seems fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was some functions in one of the javascript files and also the validation.js file, I updated it and commented the functions in conflict, the page is working good!! Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad you figured it out. For the record, `grep` is a command line utility used to search text. From your terminal, you would go to your site root and type: `grep -rn "v.ement.remove" *`. This will recursively search through the content of all the files in your site. Alternatively, you can use your text editors "Multi-File Search and Replace" feature.